# Java agent reports "redefineClasses is not supported in this environment"

Tags: java, javaagents

I'm newbie on java agents.
I created a simple HotswapAgent class (sniffing from Play! Framework):

```java
  public class HotswapAgent {
        static Instrumentation instrumentation;
        public static boolean enabled = false;

        public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation instrumentation) 
        {
             HotswapAgent.instrumentation = instrumentation;
             HotswapAgent.enabled = true;
        }

        public static void reload(ClassDefinition... definitions) 
                             throws UnmodifiableClassException, ClassNotFoundException                         
        {
            instrumentation.redefineClasses(definitions);
        }
    }
```

With this manifest:

```java
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Premain-Class: path.to.HotswapAgent
Can-Redefine-Classes: true
```

And I try to reload a new class definition, in this way:

```java
CtClass modelClass = .... 

...

byte [] bcode = modelClass.toBytecode();
Class c = modelClass.toClass();
modelClass.defrost();

ClassDefinition cdef = new ClassDefinition(c, bcode);
HotswapAgent.reload(cdef);
```

All this classes are in a jar, and finally I obtain this error (on reload() call):

```java
redefineClasses is not supported in this environment
```

But in Manifest is declared `Can-Redefine-Classes: true`.

The JVM is standard MacOS X Java 1.6 VM. This JVM works good with JRebel, that uses the same agent mechanism.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#RedefineClasses):

```
Optional Functionality: might not be implemented for all virtual machines. The following capability (as returned by GetCapabilities) must be true to use this function.
```

You can try to `addCapability` to check if there is a problem with the manifest declaration.

Here is an [example of addCapability in runtime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#capabilityExamples).